# X failure on upgrade

Tags: nvidia, upgrade, xorg, login

On Ubuntu 16.04 after a recent apt-get upgrade, X login is not working.  Why?

The login screen (which I understand is X-based) is working.  However all attempts to login, including via the guest account fail.  When I switch to a text terminal and look at .xsession-errors, I see:

> X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range
>   for operation)
>     Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
>     Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
>     Value in failed request:  0x0
>     Serial number of failed request:  34
>     Current serial number in output stream:  35

The Xserver being used is NVIDIA, however it seems like this must be an Ubuntu login issue as X itself appears to be working and /var/log/Xorg.0.log is uninformative (everything looks fine).  Any ideas how to debug further?

Comment: I have the exact same issue on Ubuntu 16.04. I installed some security updates on Nov 11th, rebooted as asked and now I can't log in.

I have found that I can still log in with "GNOME Flashback (Metacity)", or if I purge my nvidia drivers (nvidia-304) that also lets me log in again.

It seems that there is some compatability issue between whatever update was applied and the nvidia driver.

Answer (score 1):

I "fixed" this problem by upgrading to nvidia-367 from nvidia-304.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to provide detail on exactly how you went about this for those who may not know how to do so. Thank you for helping!

Comment: Installing nvidia-367 fixed it for me as well. Not sure why Ubuntu still has "nvidia-current" pointing to nvidia-304 when that's clearly a very old driver that apparently has problems with the latest updates.